# Applying functions with parameters to dynamically created buttons in WP8

Tags: c#, xml, for-loop, windows-phone-8

Here I am again trying to discover the beautiful world of C# coding for Windows Phone 8 !

This time, my problem is this :

I got a XML file filled by using my app normally. Let's admit that after a few minutes, the XML file looks like this :

```
<itemList>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item Name</Name>
        //Other Item children elements here
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item 2 Name</Name>
        //Other Item children elements here
    </Item>
</itemList>
```

I successfully extracted all the informations contained in the file using a file stream and a XDocument variable, and then stored these informations in string arrays using this kind of code :

```
string[] Names;
Names = xDoc.Descendants("Name").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();
//I made the same thing for every element contained in the Items elements.
```

This string array is used to dynamically create buttons, using a for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Names.Length; i++)
{
    Button dynamicButton = new Button();
    dynamicButton.Content = Names[i];
    //other stuff on the button
    ListOfButtons.Children.Add(dynamicButton); //ListOfButton is a StackPanel.
}
```

This is working, I got my list of buttons with the good name. What I want to do now, is to make dynamic click events, which should use other informations from the XML. For example, if the user click on Item 2 button, it should display the other elements of the Item named Item 2.

I tried to add this in the for loop :

```
dynamicButton.Click += (s, e) => resume(Names[i], Element2[i], Element3[i]);
```

But this is obviously not working, as i is to its maximum value because of the for incrementing it. So, when I click on any of the buttons, I got an out of bounds exception. Even if it wasn't out, clicking on the Item 1 button will display the informations of the last element contained in the arrays.

So, what I'm looking for is a way to make every button having his own informations to display when clicked. I don't know if i'm explaining well as English isn't my main language, ask for more details if needed.

Thanks in avance !

Comment: Why don't you try using a `Dictionary` that uses `Names[i]` as key and the data to be displayed as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using MVVM would be more elegant but for the sake of simplicity I will continue to use your code-behind.

What you need is a way to store some additional data on each button for later use. You can use the `Tag` property for that. Lets assume you have a class called Data that will hold all the additional data you need. When you create a button, assign the `Tag`

```
 dynamicButton.Tag = new Data{...} //custom data class containing the needed data from Names[i], Element2[i], etc.
```

then you can use the data in the click handler like this

```
dynamicButton.Click += (s, e) => 
{
    var button = s as Button;
    var data = button.Tag as Data;
    //do whatever you want with the data
}
```

Comment: Firstly I was wondering "what, the only way is creating a new class ? There's really no easier way ?", then I tried, and this is working without any difficulty. Thanks a lot !

Comment: there is no need for a new class, you can use a Tuple but it would be less readable